# Why is [foo view] behaving differently than foo.view in my code?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, syntax, declared-property

Purely by accident I discovered that calling `[bar.view addSubview:[foo view]]` doesn't work, but `[bar.view addSubview:foo.view]` does in the following code.

```
foo=[fooViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"fooViewController" andBundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:foo.view];//here's where I swap the two commands out
[foo aFunctionThatSendsAMessageToOneOfFoosSubViews];
```

(That last line is because `foo` has some sub-views that need to be set up prior to running -- notably, a `UIWebView`.  If they haven't been instantiated before the message is sent, the message winds up going to `nil`. With `foo`.)

I thought these two were functionally identical -- that `foo.view` calls the same getter that `[foo view]` does, but in practice that's not the case; the dot syntax gets the desired results, while using the brackets winds up sending the message to `nil`.

If you'd asked me ten minutes ago, I would have told you the difference between the two expressions was 'syntax, and nothing else'.  Given that I'm clearly wrong, I need to understand HOW I'm wrong or I'm going to stumble over it again.

Comment: Did you try comparing actual output of `[foo view]` and `foo.view`? They _must_ be the same.

Comment: Actually, yes.  I used NSLog(@"View Info: %@", [foo view]) and a similar foo.view statement.  Identical -- even when I reverse them.  The appear to return the exact same thing.

Comment: When you view your code in Xcode's Assistant Editor, and choose "Assembly" from the tuxedo drop-down, do you observe any difference between using dot syntax and brackets?

Comment: @CarlVeazey In all honesty, I don't even remember which project this was originally for.  But I'll try to update this question with more info when I do.

Answer (score 3):

They are functionally equivalent. I think this is a race condition. When you first call `foo.view` in that code, the view is not loaded yet, and a call is sent to `[foo loadView]`. You can't be sure that the view is loaded until `[foo viewDidLoad]` is called or `foo.isViewLoaded == YES`.

You need to wait make sure the view is loaded before performing any actions that rely on it, such as `[foo aFunctionThatSendsAMessageToOneOfFoosSubViews]`.

In your current case, sometimes it is loading in time and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: The problem with this answer (specifically, race condition) is that this is consistent over multiple tests.  One approach works, the other does not.

Comment: Calling `self.view` forces the view to load _synchronously_.

Answer (score -3):

if i'm not mistaken the problem is that [foo view] tries to call a method named view (and if you don't have it the return is nil)

on the other hand in the case of foo.view, view is a property of the class

Comment: When you synthesize a property, it creates getter and setter methods. The default methods (which `UIViewController` uses for the `view` property) are `- (void)setProperty:(PropertyClass *)property;` for the setter and `- (PropertyClass *)property;` for the getter

Comment: Additionally, if you tried to call a method that didn't exist, the app would crash due to an Unrecognized Selector error.

Comment: yea..so i looked through `UIViewController.h` and the thing is that the property calls `[self loadView]` while `['class' view]` doesn't

Comment: The point is that viewController.view and [viewController view] are equivalent. The OP was correct in his original understanding and I believe his error is occurring for a different reason.

Comment: Hey may be mistaken, but the idea that I'm getting a return of nil is interesting...  I'll run some NSLogs to see what comes out of that.

Comment: Actually, the thought that the property calls [self loadView] is...  possibly a solution to this type of issue in general.  (I've run into the 'have to get the view on the screen before sending it a message' issue a few times...)  (Oh, and if you made that an actual answer, you'd be much better off in terms of my accepting it...)

Comment: it wasn't an answer..it was more of an observation on whats happening here and the difference between a property and a method